# IBM Worklight - Error handling in WL.Server.notifyAllDevices

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Currently the WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, options) is used
to send notification to all a user’s devices.

Is there any callback from WL.Server.notifyAllDevices to indicate the status of this API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no callback.

The reason is that after Worklight dispatches the notifications to the various mediators (APN, MPN, GCM) they then send the notifications to the devices. However, These very same mediators do not guarantee that the notifications will arrive to their destination, as such, Worklight cannot either.

What WL.Server.notifyAllDevices does in fact is place the notifications in an internal queue, and they are then sent to the mediators. In Worklight 6.0 there is [a new return value](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_method_wl_server_notifyalldevi.html) but it is not a callback per se for what you wanted (but again, there can't be such a callback...).

Comment: Yes, noted that the mediators will not guarantee the notification will arrive to their destination. But seems that there can be error response from the mediators (Reference: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html). I think in Worklight 6 the timeout function is based on these error response from the mediators. Is there any way to "catch" these error? (I am using Worklight 5.0.6) Many Thanks!!

Comment: The new return value in 6.0 is not related to the mediators but rather to notify the backend to wait with adding more notifications to the queue (from which notifications are delivered to the mediators to be sent to devices). APN does not return any response, MPN and GCM do. After the notifyAllDevices function did its job, which is to add the notification to the internal queue, it has finished its job. The response from the mediator is not related to it. The response is more for the server than the developer - remove subscription from database, invalid id, etc. These are handled by Worklight.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. How about Apple Feedback Service (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)? Will Worklight handle this from APNS?

Comment: The answer is yes as well.

Comment: So can I say that if there is timeout from mediators (e.g. network connection problem), there is no way in Worklight API (although error code is returned from the mediators through Apple Feedback Service / GCM Error Response) to know that there is timeout?